# Responsive web design CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I’m currently working on a responsive website. I want the webpage to retain its aspect ratio when viewed on any device. I have used the viewport. But it didn’t change much. How can I do this using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By retain, do you mean the same size in pixels? If so, you can do so by setting the size of the container divs in pixels.

IF however, as per your title, you mean preserve the proportions, then you can do it by simply setting the widths and heights in percentages, or using vh and vw.